# Is there any case, barring strings or macro invocations, where `(<` is a valid stream of characters?

Tags: c++

Does there exist a case where the character `(` directly followed by `<` would be valid C++ (except for when inside a string)?

Assuming the translation unit has been pre-processed and no macros exist.

Comment: Do you mean `(<` just by itself with nothing following it or preceding it?

Comment: Also, do you mean `(` and `<` *tokens*, or *characters*? The answer might depend on that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, this is after preprocessing. I'm more interested in characters. This means that if `(<` may not be valid, but `(<=` would be, that would make the overall answer "yes".

Comment: If it's about characters, I suggest correcting the title.

Comment: 0x499602D2 No, occurring anywhere in the file.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, why? Are you parsing C++ or something like that?

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Looking into a token transformation preprocessor, not so much a parser - but yes. I was looking for a marker token to signal the start of a DSL run. libclang will probably be used anyway, but I was just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
int main()
{
    (<::>{});
}
```

Here, `<:` and `:>` are alternative spellings for `[` and `]` respectively.

Comment: I was about to post that. :)

Comment: TIL, this is why I didn't assume :) thank you! Will accept after the blackout period.